# docker not installing dependencies (node_modules) on host machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

When I run `docker-compose build` I see that dependencies from package.json are being installed on the container but not on my machine. So afterwards when I run `docker-compose up` I get errors that dependencies are not found, i.e: `Error: Cannot find module 'express'`

My app structure is very simple and looks like this:

```
|____frontend
| |____index.html
| |____index.js
| |____webpack.config.js
| |____yarn.lock
| |____package.json
| |____dev.Dockerfile
|____backend
| |____server.js
| |____yarn.lock
| |____package.json
| |____dev.Dockerfile
|____docker-compose.yml
```

my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"

services:

    frontend:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: frontend/dev.Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./frontend:/frontend:cached
        command: yarn start

    backend:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: backend/dev.Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./backend:/backend:cached
        command: yarn start
```

And this is a Dockerfile for frontend (backend looks the same):

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR "/frontend/"

COPY frontend/package.json frontend/package.json

COPY frontend/yarn.lock frontend/yarn.lock

RUN yarn
```

What is wrong with this config? What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see where you install the dependencies.

Comment: I'm using a package manager called `yarn`. In my dockerfiles I have a `RUN yarn` command, which is supposed to install dependencies

Comment: Oh, I didn't know command `yarn` alone installed the dependencies. I always use `yarn install`.
About your problem I would start by checking the `package.json` to see if `express` is included as dependency, and also check the `node_modules` folder that gets created after the installation made by yarn to see if there is a express folder, where the library should be installed if everything is done right.

Answer (score 5):

I was running into a similar problem and solved it by adding an anonymous volume to my node_modules directory in my docker-compose file. So the volumes in your docker-compose file would look like this:

```
volumes:
  - './frontend:/frontend:cached'
  - '/frontend/node_modules'
```

I got the idea from [this](http://mherman.org/blog/2017/12/07/dockerizing-a-react-app/) blog post